# How to print multiple row down JSON result?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON result like this:

```
["D002","D003","L159"]
```

Here the function:

```
function getdriverworking() {
    //my db
    $conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME) or die("FAIL");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM config_driver WHERE status=3 OR status=2";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        
    $object_array[] = $row['id_driver']."\n";

    }return $object_array;
}
```

and I call the function from here:

```
$total = getdriverworking();
$total1=json_encode($total);
$driver = "Driver Working:\n*$total1*";
    $result = [
        'mode' => 'chat', 
        'message' => $driver
    ];

print json_encode($result);
```

I pass it to WhatsApp chat, output like this:

[image]

How to make it to down like this:

```
D002
D003
L159
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand but try this :

```php
$total = getdriverworking();
$total1 = implode("\n", $total);
$driver = "Driver Working:\n*$total1*";
    $result = [
        'mode' => 'chat', 
        'message' => $driver
    ];

print json_encode($result);
```

Comment: the result : ```["D002\n","L159\n","D012\n"]```

Comment: ok solved with this:

```
$total = getdriveronline();
foreach ($total as $list) {
 $listonline .= $list . "\r\n";
}

```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:

[w3schools - JSON PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp)

> ```
> <?php
> $myObj->name = "John";
> $myObj->age = 30;
> $myObj->city = "New York";
>
> $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
>
> echo $myJSON;
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the values into a separate string.

```
$total = getdriverworking();
$total1=json_encode($total);
$driver = "Driver Working:\n*$total1*";
    $result = [
        'mode' => 'chat', 
        'message' => $driver
    ];
$str = "";
foreach ($result as $value) {
  $str += $value . "\n";
}

print json_encode($str);
```